# Grails change Environment from Development to Test

Tags: grails, development-environment, test-environments, buildconfig

Is there any way to change current environment from DEVELOPMENT to TEST?

I have tried,

```
if(Environment.getCurrent().equals(Environment.DEVELOPMENT)){
    Environment.currentEnvironment = Environment.TEST
    println("Current Environment : "+Environment.getCurrent())
}
```

But it is showing error like :

```
Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Cannot set readonly property: currentEnvironment for class: grails.util.Environment
```

How can I change this ENVIRONMENT property?

I need to change my development environment into TEST for some AES encryption algorithms, as it is not working in Development environment.

Now am using `grails test run-app` command for running app in test environment, How can I fix it in TEST environment permanently?

Comment: You could set an environment variable with the name of `grails.env` to the value of `test`. However, this would apply to all Grails applications on that machine/computer. The real solution would be to address whatever issue you are having with your AES encryption that prevents it from working correctly in your development environment.